# Как убрать отступы перед и после картинки?

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument, richtextbox

Текст

```
            Paragraph par1 = new Paragraph();
            Run txt1 = new Run(s1);
            par1.Inlines.Add(txt1);
            text_rich.Document.Blocks.Add(par1);
```

Так вставляются картинки с отступами. Перед картинками и после отступы.

```
            Image image = new Image();
            image.Source = bs;
            BlockUIContainer cont = new BlockUIContainer(image);
            Figure figure = new Figure(cont);

            figure.Width = (new FigureLength(bs.Width));
            par1.Inlines.Add(figure);

            text_rich.Document.Blocks.Add(par1);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вставляются картинки в одну строку

```
            BitmapSource bs = bi;
            Clipboard.SetImage(bi);
            text_rich.Paste();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так должно быть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Решено заменой контейнера на InlineUIContainer

```
            Image image = new Image();
            image.Source = bs;
            InlineUIContainer cont = new InlineUIContainer(image);              

            par1.Inlines.Add(cont);
            text_rich.Document.Blocks.Add(par1);
```